# Pig Generate results in empty set

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm working on a fairly basic Pig Latin script, and I run into a problem as soon as I perform a GENERATE.  Before the GENERATE, a dump shows the data looks as I expect. However, once I do the GENERATE, the results are an empty set. Based on the Pig Latin Reference manual, this appears to be correct. When the script runs I don't get any errors (it reports success.)  This occurs if I use name or positional notation for the fields during the LOAD.

My script:

```
B = LOAD 'data';
DUMP B;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE (int)$2, (int)$3, (int)$4;
DESCRIBE C;
DUMP C;
```

This is the output:

```
(2014-01-26 08:14:21,672,1,0,1,55,...)
(2014-01-26 08:14:23,654,1,1,0,55,...)

C: {f1: int,f2: int,f3: int}

(,,)
(,,)
```

Why doesn't the output from DUMP C yield (1,0,1), (1,1,0) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data file is comma-separated. By default, the loading function will parse tab-delimited records.
You can use the PigStorage loader to read character-delimited records:

```
B = LOAD 'data' USING PigStorage(',');
```